# Getting number of calls to a mock

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Assume I want to test code like this:

```
class ClassToTest
  // UsedClass1 contains a method UsedClass2 thisMethod() {}
  UsedClass1 foo;
  void aMethod()
  {
    int max = new Random().nextInt(100);
    for(i = 0; i < max; i++)
    {
      foo.thisMethod().thatMethod();
    }
  }
}
```

If I have a test like this:

```
ClassToTest test;
UsedClass1 uc1;
UsedClass2 uc2;
@Test
public void thingToTest() {
  test = new ClassToTest();
  uc1 = mock(UsedClass1.class);
  uc2 = mock(UsedClass2.class);
  when(uc1.thisMethod()).thenReturn(uc2);
  when(uc2.thatMethod()).thenReturn(true);

  test.aMethod();

  // I would like to do this
  verifyEquals(callsTo(uc1.thisMethod()), callsTo(uc2.thatMethod()));
}
```

How can I get the number of calls to `uc1.thisMethod()` and `uc2.thatMethod()` so I can check they were both called the same number of times?

Comment: The only way I can think of (right now) is to place a wrapper around each method, which increments it's own counter each time it's called. AFAIK the jvm doesn't keep track of the number of times any method/class is called/instanced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom VerificationMode to count the invocations, here you go:

```
public class InvocationCounter {

    public static <T> T countInvocations(T mock, AtomicInteger count) {
        return Mockito.verify(mock, new Counter(count));
    }

    private InvocationCounter(){}

    private static class Counter implements VerificationInOrderMode, VerificationMode {
        private final AtomicInteger count;

        private Counter(AtomicInteger count) {
            this.count = count;
        }

        public void verify(VerificationData data) {
            count.set(data.getAllInvocations().size());
        }

        public void verifyInOrder(VerificationDataInOrder data) {
            count.set(data.getAllInvocations().size());
        }

        @Override
        public VerificationMode description(String description) {
            return VerificationModeFactory.description(this, description);
        }

    }

}
```

And then use it like this (works also with void return types):

```
@Mock
private Function<String, Integer> callable;

AtomicInteger count= new AtomicInteger(); //here is the actual invocation count stored

countInvocations(callable,count).apply( anyString());

assertThat(count.get(),is(2));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, for some reason this approach didn't work for me. It just wasn't updating the counters. So, I've used the approach mentioned in the answer by @antoniob - with _doAnswer(...)_ - and it worked.

Answer (score 21):

You can do something like this:

```
YourService serviceMock = Mockito.mock(YourService.class);

// code using YourService

// details of all invocations including methods and arguments
Collection<Invocation> invocations = Mockito.mockingDetails(serviceMock).getInvocations();
// just a number of calls of any mock's methods
int numberOfCalls = invocations.size();
```

If you want only the invocations of certain method/param combination you, you can do so with

```
int specificMethodCall = Mockito.mockingDetails(serviceMock.myMethod(myParam)).getInvocations()
```

Comment: That is great. But with a little defect is that All invocations of mock are count here.

Comment: @JakubKubrynski do you know how to make  Mockito.mockingDetails(serviceMock.myMethod(myParam)).getInvocations() work when serviceMock.myMethod(myParam) doesn't return anything(void)?

Comment: @committedandroider have you tried calling `mockingDetails(serviceMock).getInvocations()` and then filtering the result list for your method name?

Answer (score 10):

You could stub your methods, and increment a counter, like this:

```
final AtomicInteger countCall1 = new AtomicInteger();

Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer<UsedClass2>() {
    @Override
    public UsedClass2 answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {
        countCall1.incrementAndGet();
        return uc2;
    }
}).when(uc1).thisMethod();
```

Comment: Out of interest, why the `AtomicInteger`?

Comment: To make the method thread-safe. If thisMethod is called by different threads, the AtomicInteger allows to increment the counter safely.

Comment: Ok, I assumed that was your reason, but thought I'd check (particularly since the the example code didn't include multiple threads).

Comment: Easiest working solution, also lambda syntax compatible as AtomicInteger can be final variable

Answer (score 5):

If you know the number of times a method is suppoed to be called you can use the `times()` method of Mockito

```
//for example if had to be called 3 times
verify(uc1, times(3)).thisMethod();
verify(uc2, times(3)).thatMethod();
```

However, I now see that you call the method a random number of times, so this probably isn't the best answer unless you stub out the random number generator to always return an expected value.

Comment: The random number was just an example - since we already have the count of calls available indirectly via the `times()` method, it seems odd that there is no way to access that count directly.